# Posting multi-part data (image with extra fields) in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js, vuejs2, multipartform-data

I recently began learning Web development using Vue JS (like 2-3 days back).

We have a backend Java Spring server which is configured to accept images and extra fields. User needs to enter the docType and image(s) and when he clicks on submit button, it should send {docType, image(s) file, userId, taskType} to server.

I have been trying to post multi part data but without success. Someone suggested yesterday that I use Axios to post but maybe I am using it wrong.

I am currently getting the error: "400 (Bad Request)" Using Chrome's *Advanced Rest Client* I can post it as multi-part so I'm kind of sure that back-end URL is correct and is working fine. 
I'd really appreciate if I can understand which parts I'm getting right and what all is wrong and should be tweaked.
Thanks!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE Html>
        <head></head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <div id="app">
<form>
                    <div>
                <label>DocType</label>
                <input type="text" name="docType" required>
                <input type="file" multiple name="file" required / @change="fieldChange">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" @click="uploadFile" >Submit
            </div>
        </form> 
        </div>

        <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data:{         
                },
                data(){
                return  {
                    attachment: null,
                    formData: new FormData,
                    userID:'',
                    taskType:'',
                    docType:''  
                         }          
                     },
                methods: {
                    fieldChange(e){
                        console.log(e);
                        let selectedFile=e.target.files[0];
                        this.attachment=selectedFile;
                    },
                    uploadFile: function(event){
                        event.preventDefault()
                       this.formData.append('userID', "1234567")
                       this.formData.append('taskType',"task1")
                       this.formData.append('file',this.attachment)
                       this.form.append('docType',"doc1")
                      axios.post('http://server:port/uploadURL',     this.formData.config).then(response=>{
                        const config = {'accept': 'application/json',
                        headers:{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}'}};
                       //

                            //success
                        })
                        .catch(response=>{
                            //error
                        })
                    }


                }
        });
        </script>
        <style> 
        </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

Instead of putting formData in data, move it to your method:

```
uploadFile: function(){
 //be sure to give your form an id
 var form = document.getElementById("form_edit");
 var formData = new FormData(form);
     //the file should already be in formData at this point
     //append other stuff as needed
     formData.append('userID', "1234567")

    axios.post('http://server:port/uploadURL', formData).then(...
     //check the console to see what is submitted in formData 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the changes. I modified the code accordingly. But it still gives me error. Upon looking at the network tab in Dev tools, I found the error to be:
Error 400: Required String parameter &#39;userID&#39 is not present.